# How do I apply custom filter in http request?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to apply filter from the http request.

I have something like

html

```
<div ng-repeat="product in products | testFilter:5 "> {{product.title}} </div>
```

js

```
app.controller('test', function($scope, $filter){
   myService.get('api/v1/products/?id=1').success(function(data) {
       $scope.products = data;    

   })
}

app.filter('testFilter', function() {
      return function(products, item) {             
          //codes...
          var t = products.length
      }
})
```

The filter works "AFTER" I got the data back from `myService`. However, while the data is loading, I keep getting `'Cannot read property 'length' of undefined'`. I know it's because the data is still loading. How do I solve this issue? Thanks.

Comment: Initialize `$scope.products` to an empty array `[]`, then when the data does load, update it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to initialise $scope.products before making the ajax call.

Something like:
`$scope.products = [];`
should do it!